How to stop tag from showing in Jupyter Lab TOC
I am not sure what happened, but previously the table of contents for my ipynb files did not show the tags in the table of contents, meaning that if the following markdown cell was in the notebook:
# Parentheses <a id="parentheses"></a>

It would display only the word "Parentheses" as an H1 heading.  It would not show the anchor tag <a id="parentheses"></a> in the table of contents.
However, now it does.  I've tried messing with the settings, or changing to different environments, but I haven't found a way to go back to not showing the tags.
I couldn't find a solution in the docs
I would think it's impossible, except that I KNOW that it wasn't showing the tags for the last ~year. I really wish I knew what changed.
EDIT
I have realized that launching jupyter lab from an older conda environment fixes the problem, so apparently some conda update that I did caused the markdown in my TOCs to no longer render.  I'm not sure which module(s) is(are) causing the problem.
Screenshot when markdown renders in TOC:

Screenshot when markdown DOES NOT render in TOC:

Here is the environment in which markdown does not render in the Table of Contents
I'm including every module, because I don't know which one is the problem
Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
aiofiles                  22.1.0          py310haa95532_0
aiosqlite                 0.18.0          py310haa95532_0
anyio                     4.2.0           py310haa95532_0
aom                       3.7.1                h63175ca_0    conda-forge
appdirs                   1.4.4              pyhd3eb1b0_0
argon2-cffi               21.3.0             pyhd3eb1b0_0
argon2-cffi-bindings      21.2.0          py310h2bbff1b_0
asttokens                 2.0.5              pyhd3eb1b0_0
async-lru                 2.0.4           py310haa95532_0
attrs                     23.2.0             pyh71513ae_0    conda-forge
babel                     2.11.0          py310haa95532_0
backcall                  0.2.0              pyhd3eb1b0_0
beautifulsoup4            4.12.2          py310haa95532_0
blas                      1.0                         mkl
bleach                    4.1.0              pyhd3eb1b0_0
bottleneck                1.3.7           py310h9128911_0
brotli                    1.0.9                h2bbff1b_8
brotli-bin                1.0.9                h2bbff1b_8
brotli-python             1.0.9           py310hd77b12b_8
brotlipy                  0.7.0           py310h2bbff1b_1002
bzip2                     1.0.8                h2bbff1b_6
ca-certificates           2024.3.11            haa95532_0
certifi                   2024.2.2        py310haa95532_0
cffi                      1.16.0          py310h2bbff1b_1
charset-normalizer        2.0.4              pyhd3eb1b0_0
colorama                  0.4.6           py310haa95532_0
comm                      0.2.1           py310haa95532_0
contourpy                 1.2.0           py310h59b6b97_0
cryptography              42.0.5          py310h89fc84f_1
cycler                    0.11.0             pyhd3eb1b0_0
dav1d                     1.2.1                h2bbff1b_0
debugpy                   1.6.7           py310hd77b12b_0
decorator                 5.1.1              pyhd3eb1b0_0
defusedxml                0.7.1              pyhd3eb1b0_0
entrypoints               0.4             py310haa95532_0
et_xmlfile                1.1.0           py310haa95532_0
exceptiongroup            1.2.0           py310haa95532_0
executing                 0.8.3              pyhd3eb1b0_0
expat                     2.6.2                hd77b12b_0
ffmpeg                    6.1.0           gpl_h0859920_103    conda-forge
font-ttf-dejavu-sans-mono 2.37                 hd3eb1b0_0
font-ttf-inconsolata      2.001                hcb22688_0
font-ttf-source-code-pro  2.030                hd3eb1b0_0
font-ttf-ubuntu           0.83                 h8b1ccd4_0
fontconfig                2.14.2               hbde0cde_0    conda-forge
fonts-anaconda            1                    h8fa9717_0
fonts-conda-ecosystem     1                    hd3eb1b0_0
fonttools                 4.51.0          py310h2bbff1b_0
freetype                  2.12.1               ha860e81_0
giflib                    5.2.1                h8cc25b3_3
glib                      2.78.4               hd77b12b_0
glib-tools                2.78.4               hd77b12b_0
gst-plugins-base          1.22.3               h23ce68f_0
gstreamer                 1.22.3               h2bbff1b_0
h11                       0.14.0          py310haa95532_0
h2                        4.1.0              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
hpack                     4.0.0                      py_0
httpcore                  1.0.5              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
httpx                     0.27.0             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
hyperframe                6.0.1              pyhd3eb1b0_0
icc_rt                    2022.1.0             h6049295_2
icu                       70.1                 h0e60522_0    conda-forge
idna                      3.7             py310haa95532_0
importlib-metadata        7.1.0              pyha770c72_0    conda-forge
importlib_metadata        7.1.0                hd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
importlib_resources       6.4.0              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
intel-openmp              2023.1.0         h59b6b97_46320
ipykernel                 6.28.0          py310haa95532_0
ipympl                    0.9.4              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
ipython                   8.20.0          py310haa95532_0
ipython_genutils          0.2.0              pyhd3eb1b0_1
ipywidgets                8.1.2           py310haa95532_0
jedi                      0.18.1          py310haa95532_1
jinja2                    3.1.3           py310haa95532_0
joblib                    1.4.0           py310haa95532_0
jpeg                      9e                   h2bbff1b_1
json5                     0.9.6              pyhd3eb1b0_0
jsonschema                4.22.0             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
jsonschema-specifications 2023.12.1          pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
jupyter                   1.0.0           py310haa95532_9
jupyter-lsp               2.2.5              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
jupyter_client            8.6.0           py310haa95532_0
jupyter_console           6.6.3           py310haa95532_0
jupyter_core              5.5.0           py310haa95532_0
jupyter_events            0.8.0           py310haa95532_0
jupyter_server            2.10.0          py310haa95532_0
jupyter_server_fileid     0.9.0           py310haa95532_0
jupyter_server_terminals  0.4.4           py310haa95532_1
jupyter_server_ydoc       0.8.0           py310haa95532_1
jupyter_ydoc              0.2.4           py310haa95532_0
jupyterlab                4.1.8              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
jupyterlab_pygments       0.1.2                      py_0
jupyterlab_server         2.27.1             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
jupyterlab_widgets        3.0.10          py310haa95532_0
kiwisolver                1.4.4           py310hd77b12b_0
krb5                      1.20.1               h5b6d351_0
lcms2                     2.12                 h83e58a3_0
lerc                      3.0                  hd77b12b_0
libbrotlicommon           1.0.9                h2bbff1b_8
libbrotlidec              1.0.9                h2bbff1b_8
libbrotlienc              1.0.9                h2bbff1b_8
libclang                  15.0.7          default_h3a3e6c3_5    conda-forge
libclang13                15.0.7          default_hf64faad_5    conda-forge
libdeflate                1.17                 h2bbff1b_1
libffi                    3.4.4                hd77b12b_1
libglib                   2.78.4               ha17d25a_0
libiconv                  1.17                 hcfcfb64_2    conda-forge
libogg                    1.3.5                h2bbff1b_1
libopus                   1.3.1                h8ffe710_1    conda-forge
libpng                    1.6.39               h8cc25b3_0
libsodium                 1.0.18               h62dcd97_0
libsqlite                 3.45.3               hcfcfb64_0    conda-forge
libtiff                   4.5.1                hd77b12b_0
libvorbis                 1.3.7                he774522_0
libwebp                   1.3.2                hbc33d0d_0
libwebp-base              1.3.2                h2bbff1b_0
libxml2                   2.12.7               h283a6d9_0    conda-forge
libxslt                   1.1.39               h3df6e99_0    conda-forge
libzlib                   1.2.13               hcfcfb64_5    conda-forge
lxml                      5.2.2           py310hdccf185_0    conda-forge
lz4-c                     1.9.4                h2bbff1b_1
markupsafe                2.1.3           py310h2bbff1b_0
matplotlib                3.8.4           py310haa95532_0
matplotlib-base           3.8.4           py310h4ed8f06_0
matplotlib-inline         0.1.6           py310haa95532_0
mistune                   2.0.4           py310haa95532_0
mkl                       2023.1.0         h6b88ed4_46358
mkl-service               2.4.0           py310h2bbff1b_1
mkl_fft                   1.3.8           py310h2bbff1b_0
mkl_random                1.2.4           py310h59b6b97_0
munkres                   1.1.4                      py_0
nb_conda_kernels          2.3.1           py310haa95532_0
nbclassic                 1.0.0           py310haa95532_0
nbclient                  0.8.0           py310haa95532_0
nbconvert                 7.10.0          py310haa95532_0
nbconvert-core            7.10.0             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
nbformat                  5.9.2           py310haa95532_0
nest-asyncio              1.6.0           py310haa95532_0
notebook                  6.5.4              pyha770c72_0    conda-forge
notebook-shim             0.2.3           py310haa95532_0
numexpr                   2.8.7           py310h2cd9be0_0
numpy                     1.26.4          py310h055cbcc_0
numpy-base                1.26.4          py310h65a83cf_0
openh264                  2.4.0                h63175ca_0    conda-forge
openjpeg                  2.4.0                h4fc8c34_0
openpyxl                  3.1.2           py310h2bbff1b_0
openssl                   3.3.0                hcfcfb64_0    conda-forge
overrides                 7.4.0           py310haa95532_0
packaging                 23.2            py310haa95532_0
pandas                    2.2.1           py310h5da7b33_0
pandocfilters             1.5.0              pyhd3eb1b0_0
parso                     0.8.3              pyhd3eb1b0_0
patsy                     0.5.3           py310haa95532_0    anaconda
pcre                      8.45                 hd77b12b_0
pcre2                     10.42                h0ff8eda_1
pickleshare               0.7.5           pyhd3eb1b0_1003
pillow                    10.3.0          py310h2bbff1b_0
pip                       24.0            py310haa95532_0
pkgutil-resolve-name      1.3.10          py310haa95532_1
platformdirs              3.10.0          py310haa95532_0
ply                       3.11            py310haa95532_0
pooch                     1.7.0           py310haa95532_0
prometheus_client         0.14.1          py310haa95532_0
prompt-toolkit            3.0.43          py310haa95532_0
prompt_toolkit            3.0.43               hd3eb1b0_0
psutil                    5.9.0           py310h2bbff1b_0
pure_eval                 0.2.2              pyhd3eb1b0_0
pybind11-abi              5                    hd3eb1b0_0
pycparser                 2.21               pyhd3eb1b0_0
pygments                  2.15.1          py310haa95532_1
pyopenssl                 24.0.0          py310haa95532_0
pyparsing                 3.0.9           py310haa95532_0
pyqt                      5.15.10         py310hd77b12b_0
pyqt5-sip                 12.13.0         py310h2bbff1b_0
pyrsistent                0.20.0          py310h2bbff1b_0
pysocks                   1.7.1           py310haa95532_0
python                    3.10.14         h4de0772_0_cpython    conda-forge
python-dateutil           2.9.0post0      py310haa95532_2
python-fastjsonschema     2.16.2          py310haa95532_0
python-json-logger        2.0.7           py310haa95532_0
python-tzdata             2023.3             pyhd3eb1b0_0
python_abi                3.10                    4_cp310    conda-forge
pytz                      2024.1          py310haa95532_0
pywin32                   305             py310h2bbff1b_0
pywinpty                  2.0.10          py310h5da7b33_0
pyyaml                    6.0.1           py310h2bbff1b_0
pyzmq                     25.1.2          py310hd77b12b_0
qt-main                   5.15.8               h720456b_6    conda-forge
qt-webengine              5.15.9               h5bd16bc_7
qtconsole                 5.5.1           py310haa95532_0
qtconsole-base            5.5.2              pyha770c72_0    conda-forge
qtpy                      2.4.1           py310haa95532_0
qtwebkit                  5.212                h992fabe_8    conda-forge
referencing               0.35.1             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
requests                  2.32.2          py310haa95532_0
rfc3339-validator         0.1.4           py310haa95532_0
rfc3986-validator         0.1.1           py310haa95532_0
rpds-py                   0.18.0          py310h87d50f1_0    conda-forge
scikit-learn              1.4.2           py310h4ed8f06_1
scipy                     1.13.0          py310h8640f81_0
send2trash                1.8.2           py310haa95532_0
setuptools                69.5.1          py310haa95532_0
sip                       6.7.12          py310hd77b12b_0
six                       1.16.0             pyhd3eb1b0_1
sniffio                   1.3.0           py310haa95532_0
soupsieve                 2.5             py310haa95532_0
sqlite                    3.45.3               h2bbff1b_0
stack_data                0.2.0              pyhd3eb1b0_0
statsmodels               0.14.0          py310h9128911_0
svt-av1                   1.7.0                h63175ca_0    conda-forge
tbb                       2021.8.0             h59b6b97_0
terminado                 0.17.1          py310haa95532_0
threadpoolctl             2.2.0              pyh0d69192_0
tinycss2                  1.2.1           py310haa95532_0
tk                        8.6.14               h0416ee5_0
toml                      0.10.2             pyhd3eb1b0_0
tomli                     2.0.1           py310haa95532_0
tornado                   6.3.3           py310h2bbff1b_0
traitlets                 5.7.1           py310haa95532_0
typing-extensions         4.11.0          py310haa95532_0
typing_extensions         4.11.0          py310haa95532_0
tzdata                    2024a                h04d1e81_0
ucrt                      10.0.22621.0         h57928b3_0    conda-forge
unicodedata2              15.1.0          py310h2bbff1b_0
urllib3                   2.2.1           py310haa95532_0
vc                        14.2                 h2eaa2aa_1
vc14_runtime              14.38.33135         h835141b_20    conda-forge
vs2015_runtime            14.38.33135         h22015db_20    conda-forge
wcwidth                   0.2.5              pyhd3eb1b0_0
webencodings              0.5.1           py310haa95532_1
websocket-client          1.8.0           py310haa95532_0
wheel                     0.43.0          py310haa95532_0
widgetsnbextension        4.0.10          py310haa95532_0
win_inet_pton             1.1.0           py310haa95532_0
winpty                    0.4.3                         4
x264                      1!164.3095           h8ffe710_2    conda-forge
x265                      3.5                  h2d74725_3    conda-forge
xz                        5.4.6                h8cc25b3_1
y-py                      0.5.9           py310hb6bf4ef_0
yaml                      0.2.5                he774522_0
ypy-websocket             0.8.2           py310haa95532_0
zeromq                    4.3.5                hd77b12b_0
zipp                      3.17.0          py310haa95532_0
zlib                      1.2.13               hcfcfb64_5    conda-forge
zstd                      1.5.5                hd43e919_2


There is an ignore setting but it ignores the entire heading. I wonder if this here would cover what you desire and more because it restores the older flavor of table of contents? And there are some issues posted about related things here.

I realize what is happening now - the markdown is showing verbatim in the TOC.  For example, when I create a markdown cell with  ## Does ***this*** format?, it creates an entry in the TOC that displays as Does ***this*** format?.  I have pulled up an old notebook that used to display the TOC formatted, and now it doesn't, so it's not an issue with the file.  Either I somehow changed a setting, or maybe I updated some module that caused the change.

Ah, yes!  I used an older environment to launch jupyter lab, and now the notebook TOC renders the markdown!  I had tried switching the kernel for the notebook to a different conda environment, but that had no effect.  It's the conda environment that I activate before launching jupyter lab that matters!

Glad you found a lead. This still may mean for a long-term solution you'll want to try that one that has more behavior in line with the old classic style or file an issue post and see if it is possible to fix or if there is a reason it is currently different.
